# PHP Removing Phone Number and E-mail from a string

Tags: php, string

I m looking for a way to remove any phone number and E-mail adress from a string.

Is anybody who have already realize that kind of function ?

What do you all recommand ?
EREG ?

Thanks 
Regards,
Titus.

PS: any tuto is huge welcomed :)

```
    $chaine = "Here is my e-Mail contact@domain.eu and my phone (works) 0606060606 (not works) 06.06.06.06.06";
// Phone Number :
$chaine = preg_replace('/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/', '[removed]', $chaine);

// E-mail adress :
$pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/";
$replacement = "[removed]";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $chaine);

echo $chaine;
```

Comment: Can you post some examples of the string? Can you also post what you've already tried? Also, FYI, ereg is deprecated; don't use it.

Comment: i success to remove phone number but not dot separated is not working. And Email doesn t work at all

Comment: Hey, @Titus. It's never too late to mark Boodle's answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic implementation. The regex for email is from [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=26). A phpfiddle can be [tested here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d2u-1s5).

```
function removeEmailAndPhoneFromString($string) {
    // remove email
    $string = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/','',$string);

    // remove phone
    $string = preg_replace('/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]+)/','',$string);

    return $string;
}

echo removeEmailAndPhoneFromString('Lorem ipsum foo@bar.com dolor sit amet, 555-123 555 consectetur adipiscing elit.');
```

The regex for the phone was just thrown together so YMMV.

Comment: That regex for email doesn't allow a plus "+" in the email address, so it's not RFC compliant. Just FYI.

Comment: The phone replace also removes short numbers, e.g. `This was 3456 days ago.` → 3456 would be replaced. Can we have a minimum length to prevent such replacements?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) for this.

The code would like a

```
    $string = 'your string';

    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/';
    $patterns[1] = '/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]+)/';

    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = '';
    $replacements[1] = '';

    //should use just one call of preg_replace for perfomance issues
    $string = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Also read

- [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)
- [Is regular expression recognition of an email address hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard)

This questions about regexp for validate phone numbers and email adress.

p.s.Sample on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/c8h-f2x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this booth functions

```
function hide_email($str){

   $pattern = "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/";
   $replacement = "[Email removed]";
   return = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);

 }
```

in the hide_telnr function there ist {4,} to tell that numbers lower 99999 are allowed

```
function hide_telnr($str){

   $pattern = "/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]+){4,}/";
   $replacement = "[Telefon Number removed]";
   return = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide email and phone numbers from your Messages or Chat in PHP or any other language. You need to use regular expressions, read about regex on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

I have an easy and complete solution for you.

```
<?php       
    $regex_email = '/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/';
    $regex_phone = "/[0-9]{5,}|\d[ 0-9 ]{1,}\d|\sone|\stwo|\sthree|\sfour|\sfive|\ssix|\sseven|\seight|\snine|\sten/i";

    
    $str = " Hello My Email soroutlove1996@gmail.com AND Phone No. is +919992799999 and +91 9992799999, or 9 9 9 2 7 9 9 9 9 9 and Nine Nine";;
    $str = preg_replace($regex_email,'(email hidden)',$str); // extract email
    $str = preg_replace($regex_phone,'(phone hidden)',$str); // extract phone
    
    echo $str;
```

> **Output:** Hello My Email (email hidden) AND Phone No. is +(phone
> hidden) and +(phone hidden), or (phone hidden) and(phone hidden)(phone
> hidden)