# How to validate Email address to check RFC822 compliance using libCurl

Tags: c, email, smtp, rfc822

I am trying to implement Email SMTP notifications in my application using libCurl in C.

Before sending notification, i want to check for RFC 822 compliance on both FROM and TO addresses.

Currently i am able to do it using JNI (JAVA  javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress class)

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/

Comment: Search for "regex email" and "regex c" on google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regexp recognition of email address hard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/387850/validate-email-without-using-regular-expression) helps.